# Raising a RealFrac to another RealFrac power

Tags: haskell, types, exponentiation

I am attempting to raise a number which is of type `RealFrac` to the power of another number, also of type `RealFrac`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400568/exponentiation-in-haskell) on exponentiation helpfully explains the various exponentiation functions in Haskell, and I believe I need to use `(^)` in order to preserve any non integer values. But how do I deal with the types? I keep coming up against errors like this:

```
Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of ‘^’
from the context (RealFrac a)
  bound by the type signature for
             splitFunc :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> a
  at Procedural/City.hs:41:16-42
Possible fix:
  add (Integral a) to the context of
    the type signature for splitFunc :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> a
In the expression: r ^ l
In an equation for ‘splitFunc’: splitFunc r l = r ^ l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues. Firstly, you do not want `(^)`, but rather `(^^)` (if your exponents are always integer numbers) or `(**)` (if you need floating exponents):

```
Prelude> :t (^)
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
Prelude> :t (^^)
(^^) :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
Prelude> :t (**)
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

Secondly, `RealFrac` covers not only floating point numbers but also, for instance, [exact fractions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html). If you really need your function to use `(**)` *and* work with any `RealFrac` you will need to convert the values with [`realToFrac`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:realToFrac):

```
Prelude> :t realToFrac 
realToFrac :: (Fractional b, Real a) => a -> b
```

Naturally, if you define `splitFunc r l = realToFrac r ** realToFrac l` and pass exact fractions (e.g. something of type `Ratio Integer`) to it, the extra precision of exact fractions will be lost, as `(**)` is a floating point operation.

Comment: Ah yes sorry i meant **. That works perfectly, thank you - its taking me a bit of time to get used to haskells type system.