# How to declare functions in Haskell with let ( single line operatoins only )

Tags: haskell

I am stuck behind a very simple exercise I just have to do `x + y ^ sqrt z` with `let`, but I tried:

```
let f x y z = x + y ^ sqrt z
```

but it doesn't work and complains about a type miss match when `f` is used and with `:t (f)` I get:

```
(f) :: (Integral b, Floating b, Num a) => a -> a -> b -> a
```

Can somebody explain or give an article which explains the `(Integral b, Floating b, Num a)` part. What I know is Num a => a "1" -> a "2" -> a "3"
for f x y = x + y

`x` has the type of `a1` and `y` has the type of `a2` and the solution is `a3` all of typeclass `Num` which is used for `(*), (+), (^), ...` .

Comment: That `(Integral b, Floating b, Num a)` bit is a _typeclass constraint_. Have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Type_constraints and http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses for some info. Another thing — there are [several different exponentiation operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6400628/7345298) in Haskell, and I think you want `**` rather than `^`.

Comment: The problem is that the `^` operator expects an integer as its second input (i.e. you can write `2 ^ 3` but you can't write `2 ^ 3.0`). However, the `sqrt` function returns a floating point number. If you want to raise a number to a floating point power then you have to use the `**` operator. For example, can write `2 ** 3.0`. Hence, your function would be `let f x y z = x + y ** sqrt z`.

Comment: Most numbers are not both `Integral` and `Floating`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-) takes as second parameter an `Integral` type. An integral type is something like an `Int`, `Integer`, etc.

But your [**`sqrt :: Floating f => f -> f`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) takes a `Floating` value and returns a `Floating` value. This thus means that the type of `z` needs to be a type that is both a member of the `Integral` and `Floating` typeclass. Although strictly speaking, it is possible to implement such types, the two typeclasses contradict each other in terms on what sort of types can be members.

You probably should use [**`(**) :: Floating f => f -> f -> f`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-) here to raise a number to a floating power. We can thus define `f` as:

```
f x y z = x + y ** sqrt z
```

Then `f` has type:

```
f :: Floating a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

It thus takes three `a`s where `a` is a type that is a member of the `Floating` typeclass, and returns an `a`.